# Identify Range levels OHLC in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, statistics

I need help in calculating levels based on OHLC data in python, Please find the sample code below. The output expected is of all the price levels with datetime, which would help me plot ranges on the charts. More detailing are commented as part of the code. Any help here would be really helpfull.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IRPK16/SampleShare/5372e0c9fe07f6e31ac2729c86209684f6af69d1/CADCHF.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                    open=df['Open'],
                    high=df['High'],
                    low=df['Low'],
                    close=df['Close']))
                    
fig.update(layout_xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.update_layout(
    title='CADCHF',
    yaxis_title='Price',
    xaxis_title='Date')

# Scenario 1: Identify normal range, currently hardcoded for last 20 bars. Need help in getting array[range1, range2,...] programatically
range_line = df.iloc[-22:].copy()
range_line['min_line'] = range_line['Close'].min()
range_line['mid_line'] = range_line['Close'].mean()
range_line['max_line'] = range_line['Close'].max()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = 'lines', x=range_line['Date'], y=range_line['min_line'], line={'color':'black', 'width':1}
    ))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = 'lines', x=range_line['Date'], y=range_line['max_line'], line={'color':'black', 'width':1}
    ))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = 'lines', x=range_line['Date'], y=range_line['mid_line'], line={'color':'black', 'width':1}
    ))
print(df)
# Scenario 2: Identify squeeze range, currently hardcoded for last 53 to 62 bars. Need help in getting such array[range1, range2,...] programatically
range_line2 = df.iloc[53:62].copy()
range_line2['min_line'] = range_line2['Close'].min()
range_line2['mid_line'] = range_line2['Close'].mean()
range_line2['max_line'] = range_line2['Close'].max()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(mode = 'lines', x=range_line2['Date'], y=range_line2['mid_line'], line={'color':'black', 'width':1}
    ))

fig.update_traces(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image: Output]

expected output is as below:

```
def detect_level_method_2(df):
levels = []
max_list = []
min_list = []
for i in range(5, len(df)-5):
    high_range = df['High'][i-5:i+4]
    current_max = high_range.max()
    if current_max not in max_list:
        max_list = []
    max_list.append(current_max)
    if len(max_list) == 5 and isFarFromLevel(current_max, levels, df):
        levels.append((high_range.idxmax(), current_max))
    
    low_range = df['Low'][i-5:i+5]
    current_min = low_range.min()
    if current_min not in min_list:
        min_list = []
    min_list.append(current_min)
    if len(min_list) == 5 and isFarFromLevel(current_min, levels, df):
        levels.append((low_range.idxmin(), current_min))
return levels
```

---

Update:
I am able to identify based on previous value, but unable to group the values based on close nearest range. Please help me in solving this problem.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IRPK16/SampleShare/5372e0c9fe07f6e31ac2729c86209684f6af69d1/CADCHF.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

dfOrderedByDateDesc = df.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=[True])
bar = dfOrderedByDateDesc.iloc[-1:].copy() # Returns last bar

from statistics import median
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df['Prev_High'] = df['High'].shift()
df['Prev_Low'] = df['Low'].shift()

df['isInRange'] = ((df['Close'] < df['Prev_High']) & (df['Close'] > df['Prev_Low']))

print(df.tail(3))
```